# Spring security integration with JSF 2: JSF component is not working

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security

I am trying to integrate Spring security with JSF. I have followed few online tutorials and did the following changes in the code to implement the same:

```
 **web.xml:**

 <!-- Add Support for Spring -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

**springsecurity.taglib.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
        <handler-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
    </tag>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAnyGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAnyGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areNotGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areNotGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>isAllowed</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean isAllowed(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

**Spring-Security.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"
    >

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cloud.temp.beans" />

<http pattern="/faces/login.xhtml" security="none"/>
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/faces/login.xhtml" access="isAnonymous()" /> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/faces/page1.xhtml" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/faces/page2.xhtml" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/faces/page3.xhtml" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login
            login-page="/faces/login.xhtml" always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/faces/error.xhtml"
         />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
                <user name="test" password="123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="tom" password="pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**LoginBean.xhtml**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.cloud.temp.resources.ApplicationConstants;

@Component
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8599275224031455540L;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    // validate login
    public String validateUsernamePassword() throws IOException,ServletException {
        String temp=null;
        try{



        Authentication request=new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.userName, this.password);
        Authentication result=authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
        if(result.isAuthenticated()){
             temp=ApplicationConstants.NAV_SUCCESS;
        }else{
             temp=ApplicationConstants.NAV_ERROR;
        }

        }catch(Exception e){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(),e.getMessage()));
        }
            return temp;


    }

}
```

With the help of above implementation, I am able to do the role based authentication. However,
Few of the JSF component is not working. For example **datatable** size is not changing, 
JSF **link** is not working. The same was working fine before implementing the spring security framework.
How to trace out the issue?

Comment: any 404/403/401 in the browser network console?

Comment: @Kukeltje: I am getting 302 error.. which mean URL redirection is happening when I am making the call. Since I have user @ Component tag for spring security.. Does It mean two controllers is creating by the code , one by JSF and one by Spring?